# Model self referential collections in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, self-reference

I have written an application for an online clothing store in Rails 2.3.5.  I want to show related Products when a customer views the Product Detail page.

For example, if the customer views the detail page for a suit, I'd like to display the accessory products that match the dress such as a vest, shoes, and belt.  I have named the related products an Ensemble.  However, the vest, shoes, and belts are also Products which is what has me struggling.

I have it working as follows but I know it's not the Rails way.  I have a Products table for all of the products.  Not important here but I also have a ProductDetails table.  I have an Ensembles table that has the following columns:

- product_id - the main or origination product, the one displayed on the detail page
- outfit_id - the related or accessory product

In setting up the data, on the Products list, for each Product I have an Ensemble link.  This link takes you to the index action in the Ensembles controller.

Using the id from the "main" Product, I find all of the associated Ensemble rows by product_id or I create a new ensemble and assign the id from the main product as the product_id.  I'd like to just be able to do @product.related_products to get an Ensemble collection.

Also on the index page I list the columns of the main product so the user can be sure their main product was the one they selected from the list.  I also have a select list of the other products, with an Add to Ensemble action.

Finally on the same index page, I have a table that displays the products that are already in the ensemble and in that list each row has a destroy link to remove a particular product from the ensemble.  It would be nice if given a single Ensemble row @ensemble I could do @ensemble.product to get the Product related to the outfit_id of the ensemble row.

I've got it working without associations but I have to run queries in the controller to build my own @product, @ensemble, and @ensembles collections.  Also the only way I found to destroy an ensemble row is by Ensemble.connection.delete(sql to delete), simple @ensemble.destroy doesn't work.

Anyone know how I would set up the associations or have a link to a site explaining a similar setup.  None of the examples I found use the same table.  They have A related to B through C.  I want A related to other A through B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your associations as follows:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :ensembles
  has_many :outfits, :through => :ensembles
end

class Ensemble < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :outfit, :class_name => "Product", :foreign_key => :outfit_id
end
```

Now you can do the following:

```
p.outfits # all ensemble products for given product.
p.outfits << p2 # add product to the ensemble of given product.
p.outfits.delete(p3) # delete product from the ensemble of given product.
```

Comment: Excellent this is how I expected it to work, but I never understood from the other examples that I could create/delete Ensemble rows based on the outfits.  I was always attempting to work with the Ensemble row itself.  Thanks for the clarity.